# Inserting dynamic-allocated objects into QHash

Tags: qt, dynamic-allocation

I have a `QHash<QString, myClass*> objects` and in order to insert I did the following:

```
myClass *value = objects.value(key);
    if(!value) {
        value = new myClass;
        objects.insert(key, value);
    }
```

Is this right approach?

Comment: yes it looks fine, but remember about memory management, consider use of smart pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is one of several possible correct approaches.

I usually do it like this as I find it a bit more readable

```
if( !objects.contains( key ) )
{
    objects.insert( key, new MyClass );
}
MyClass* value = objects.value( key);
```

As already suggested by Marek R, you can use smart pointers for easier memory management:

```
QHash< QString, QSharedPointer< MyClass > > objects;
// ...
QSharedPointer< MyClass > value = objects.value( key );
```

Since C++11, I prefer using [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

This allows you to not care about `delete` calls; just make sure you always use `QSharedPointer< MyClass >` instead of `MyClass*` everywhere. Also, you mustn't use shared pointers for QObject subclasses which have a parent, as the parent object will store a regular pointer for it.

Comment: Why does this allow you to not care about delete calls? AFAIK QPointer doesn't deal with ownership, just guards the pointer so you can reliably check it when the underlying object is deleted elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnNeuhaus You are right, I probably intended to use `QSharedPointer` in this answer. I've updated the answer, thanks for pointing that out.